# No Metrics on Azure Website Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

For some reason I have no monitoring metrics on the dashboard or monitor page for my Azure Website.

This is how my metrics appear:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have resolved itself after moving from the free account to a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a transitory/temporary issue on the management functionality. Please try again later, and try also over different duration (1 week for ex).

Comment: Hi Marius, I've been trying over 2 weeks now and still no luck. The 1 hour duration works, but only while the monitor is open. If I close the Azure dashboard and reopen, the metrics are gone. :-(